# Does a motherboard with 4 DIMMS and a max of 32 gigs mean each DIMM supports a max of 8 gigs?

Tags: memory, motherboard

My motherboard is a GA-Z97-HD3 by GIGABYTE. The specs say that it supports a max of 32 gigs RAM and has 4 DIMMs. The specs do not say what each DIMM supports.  Should I be able to install 2 sticks of 16 gig RAM or does this mean I need 4 sticks of 8 gig RAM?

Here is the spec sheet:
https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z97-HD3-rev-10#sp

Comment: It depends. Your assumption is reasonable, but it could also be wrong.

Comment: I would go off the memory compatibly list, if you find 16 GB modules on the list, then they are compatible.  If you find none there is a good chance they are not supported.

Comment: I just want to say that there are many motherboards that do not support 16GB RAM sticks. There is a good  chance they are not supported. Do as @Ramhound said to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to do what @Ramhound suggested and I also contacted GIGABYTE. They basically said that they couldn't test every type of RAM and it must not be supported. I went with 4 sticks of 8gig G.SKILL Ripjaws and it is working fine.